# How to format code only when Shift+Alt+F is pressed in VS Code? (extension)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have installed the "JS-CSS-HTML Formatter" extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter) in VS Code. When I press Shift+Alt+F, it formats the code. However, after the first time I press Shift+Alt+F, it formats code automatically every time I make a change.

I want it to format my code only when I press Shift+Alt+F, instead of it automatically formatting it after the first time I press Shift+Alt+F. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press F1 and type Formatter config.

Then change the `"onSave" : true` to `"onSave" : false`

and restart vs code